# Android Firebase Database combine multi queries

Tags: android, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I want show a list of users (using RecyclerView , adapter ...) , the list contain user's info (photo , name , email ....) and also a count of the comments about this user , for the user's info I made a firebase query and I get all the info as I want

```
al = new ArrayList<>();

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Seeker").child(categorie).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            // clear data before
            al.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot dataLoop : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String getcity = dataLoop.child("City").getValue().toString().trim();



                if (getcity.equalsIgnoreCase(City.trim())) {

                    p = new Person();

                    p.setName(dataLoop.child("Name").getValue(String.class));
                    p.setId(dataLoop.child("Id").getValue(String.class));

                    if (dataLoop.hasChild("urlToImage")) {
                        p.setUrl(dataLoop.child("urlToImage").getValue(String.class));

                    } else {
                        p.setImage(R.drawable.profile);
                    }
                    
                    readData(new MyCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCallback(String value) {
                            Log.d("TAG", value);
                            p.setComms(value);
                        }
                    }, dataLoop.child("Id").getValue(String.class));

                    al.add(p);
                }

            }
            md = new MyAdaptor(MyClass.this, al);
            rv.setAdapter(md);
        }
```

...
...

```
            public void readData(final MyCallback myCallback, String value) {
                database.child("Review").child(value).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dataLoop : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            count = dataLoop.getChildrenCount();
                            Log.d("TAG", "count = " + count);
                            p.setComms(String.valueOf(count));
                        }
                        myCallback.onCallback(String.valueOf(count));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                });
        }

        public interface MyCallback {
                void onCallback(String value);
        }
```

my problem is that I want add one more info for each user , it's the count of review for each one , I tried to make another query inside the loop but as firebase calls are asynchronous
it's not working , the layout doesn't show numbers of reviews.

here is a sample of my firebase database structure

```
-Review
    -HDGFDGDGDB (user id)
       -FSETTDGDG (user who made the review)
           -1 : review1
           -2 : review2


-Seeker
    -HDGFDGDGDB (user id)
        -city : "NY"
        -name : "Jhon"......
```

what's the best solution to combine the two queries in order to show all the info in the recyclerView.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?  Please edit the question to show that code, and explain what it's doing that isn't what you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson i edited my question , hope it's clear now.

Comment: From the added code, what exactly doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: p.setComms(value); is not working , this value is not shown on recyclerView , the person infos are shown but not this comments value. I know that the issue is that firebase requests are asynchronous.